# Get all wpf controls in cs file and check their type

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some xam controls on wpf form. I want to count the control, how much controls on the form? in cs file and also check their type either control is text box or combo box or etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount() and GetChild()